# What are space requirements for the Postgres database major version upgrade?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, upgrade

I'm using the RDS Postgres database and the current version is 11.13 and want to upgrade it to 12.10. My instance storage is 5000 GB and almost all storage is occupied. Now only ~500 GB are available.

How can we know if the storage is sufficient for a major version upgrade?

Comment: Space requirements wholly depend on the chosen upgrade method, and since you've tagged your question with "amazon-rds", you'll have to ask the AWS support about that.

Comment: With a "vanilla" Postgres you can use `pg_upgrade` with the  `--link` parameter which means the additional space overhead during migration is extremely small

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you upgrading to a version 2 full releases behind with the 3rd major release shortly coming.  Current release v14.4/ Shortly coming v15.

Comment: @Belayer For now, don't want to upgrade it to the latest version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Any idea on how much time it takes for AWS to upgrade 5TB of the database?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question except Amazon. Go ask them. You trust them, otherwise you wouldn't have turned over your data to them, right?

Comment: @Kaushalpanchal: if AWS offers Postgres 14, then you should really be upgrading to that. _If_ AWS supports running pg_upgrade with the `--link` option then the upgrade should only take a "some minutes"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres 14 is not supported at the moment. I'm not sure what AWS runs internally when we modify db engine version. Any idea?

Comment: @Kaushalpanchal I believe AWS uses `--link`, but they don't specify this in any documentation that I can find. However, my empirical testing (upgrading 12.11 to 14.4) shows that they use `--link`. I find the following logs: `Because "link" mode was used, the old cluster cannot be safely started once the new cluster has been started.` and the upgrade also completes way too fast for it to not be `--link` (less than a minute for a ~2GB database)